# Can I pass file name as a parameter to menus page arguments?

Tags: 7, hooks, files

I have a hyperlink, in that I am passing the dynamic foldernames and filenames as url like below.

```
 $data .= '<div><a href="'. $base_url.'/custom/delete/'.$foldnames.'/' .$filenames .'">' ."--". $filenames .'</a></div>';
```

When I click on this, it will go to the particular menu, in the menu I am calling a function to do delete functionality. Below is the menu implemetation

```
 $items = array();
    $items['/delete/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => "Delete Files",
    'page callback' => 'delete_public_files',
    'page arguments' => array($arg1, $arg2),
    'access arguments' => array('administer custom settings'), 
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

I am getting confused while using the arguments here. Can anybody help me that how I have to hit this `sitename/custom/delete/foldnames/filenames` url. On the samy way how can  call `delete_public_files` function with $foldnames and  $filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['custom/delete/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => "Delete Files"
    'page callback' => 'delete_public_files',
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3),
    'access arguments' => array('administer custom settings'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Please use integer in the array of `page arguments` to specify the value in url. The url is split in this format: `0/1/2/3`